# GLSL normalized texture coordinate to pixel coordinate

Tags: glsl

I've a texture (2048 x 2048) Pixels.
I am looking for an algorithm to transform the normalized texture coordinate [0 1] to pixel coordinate [0 2047]. This should be a perfect fit...

So when the texture sampler has a GL_NEAREST interpolation the following code should output the same:

```
ivec2 texSize = textureSize(tex);
vec2 normalizedCoordinate = someValue;
ivec2 pixelCoordinate = AlgorithmIamLookingFor;
vec4 color = texture(tex, normalizedCoordinate);
vec4 color2 = texelFetch(tex, pixelCoordinate, 0);
```

So `color` and `color2` should have the same value.

I've tried the following:

```
pixelCoordinate.x = int(normalizedCoordinate * 2047)
```

But the last pixel (2047) will not show up or be extremely small.

Comment: What is the sampler that is being used with the texture function? Anything but nearest will give an averaged result using a filter.

Comment: Assuming that glsl `int (myFloat)` rounds to zero, why not `pixelCoordinate = int(normalizedCoordinate * 2048)` ?

Comment: @pmw1234 like I wrote in my question: the sampler is "GL_NEAREST" so `color` will output the color of the pixel without any interpolation...

Comment: @leoneruggiero when `normalizedCoordinate.x` is 1, the output would be 2048, which is outside [0 2047]

Comment: @Thomas Have you tried? As far as I know if a primitive ends up in a pixel it means it crosses the pixel center and texture coordinates are evaluated at the pixel center for that primitive, so the only way for them to be exactly 1 is that the vertex with texCoords=1 is exactly at the center of a pixel...in that case `clamp` should solve the issue.

Comment: @Thomas Oops, that is such a common mistake I guess I typed before reading. A handy way to check texture coordinate math is compare it against gl_fragCoord in the fragment shader. (not necessarily looking for an exact match, but there should be a consistent difference, then output a strange color where they don't line up...like bright pink) This can help pinpoint casting and rounding differences as well as other trivial errors that are easy to overlook.